# Unicode characters in the URL param of Embedded Windows Media Player

Tags: url, unicode, encoding, windows-media-player

Let's take this simple HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- Object Tag For the Audio Player -->
<object id="mpAudio" width="100%" height="100%"
    classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6"
    type="application/x-oleobject" align="middle">
        <param name="URL" value="http://servername/media/Alt.TÉst/default.wav" />
        <param name="AutoStart" value="True" />
        <param name="UIMode" value="Full" />
        <param name="EnableContextMenu" value="True" />
        <param name="WindowlessVideo" value="True" />
        <param name="Mute" value="False" />
</object>
</html>
```

Notice in the URL there is this unicode character: É

When I open that html file, the audio plays as a garbled mess.  Of note, in some older VM I have (for random IE6 testing), which has an O/S of 2003 Standard Edition, an IE 6 browser, and Windows Media Player 6.4.09.1130 .. it works, fine!  My testing where it's a garbled mess, involves Windows 7, IE 10, and WMP 12.0.7601.17514

I thought the solution may be % encoding the URL.  That's even worse.  The encode became: http%3A%2F%2Fservername%2Fmedia%2FAlt.T%C3%89st%2Fdefault.wav

And I went from at least being able to play a garbled mess, to not playing anything at all.

One other test:

Taking the non-encoded url and putting it in Firefox, opens the wav (so Firefox is OK with the unicode character).  Taking the encoded url, I get "server not found".  I guess I don't know how to encode!

Barring eliminating unicode for data entry (these URLs are generated from Username's, where in some locales they allow unicode characters in the name), how do I make this work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought the solution may be % encoding the URL. That's even worse. The encode became: http%3A%2F%2Fservername%2Fmedia%2FAlt.T%C3%89st%2Fdefault.wav

The solution *should* be to URL-encode path components, rather than the whole URL. You want to end up with:

```
http://servername/media/Alt.T%C3%89st/default.wav
```

Although, I would have expected the fail case to get a 404 and just not play anything—garbled audio is a weird result. There might be a different issue as well?

Comment: Son of a gun.  I'm positive I tried that first before posting here.  I took the URL that was % encoded for me through one of these random websites I googled, and removed all the encoding except for the É.  I know I did!  I think, my mind is playing tricks on me.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: And audio is fine, I'm with you, I expected something other than garbled audio.  That one change I made (based on your advice) did the trick.